# How generate number type uint256 in Go

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, golang

My smart contract has a function like this

```
function setTest(uint256 test) returns (bool){
    testNumber = test;
    return true;
}
```

I used these piece of code Go to create a transaction to set new value to `testNumber` - a RPC call

```
var newtest uint256 = 100 // I expected this type (uint256)
abis, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(contractInterface))
output, err := abis.Pack("setTest", newtest)

params := make(map[string]string)
params["data"] = fmt.Sprintf("0x%s", common.Bytes2Hex(output))
params["from"] = self.ownerAccount
params["to"] = self.contractAccount

done := ""
err = self.client.Call(&done, "eth_sendTransaction", params)
.....
```

And the problem is I can't set **newtest** as type uint256. I can't find type uint256 in Go. Please help me, generate number type uint256 or convert from (big.Int, int64, uint64) to uint256. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

One of the Golang gurus might want to comment further, but I don't think Go supports 256-bit integers natively.

You could import Geth's [`number`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/common/number) package, together with `math/big`, and use the relevant parts.

e.g. Call [`Uint256()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/fed692f67e81bd3937a5efab38f56a9b99d04d41/common/number/int.go#L62):

```
// Return a Number with a UNSIGNED limiter up to 256 bits
func Uint256(n int64) *Number {
    return &Number{big.NewInt(n), limitUnsigned256}
}
```

Which returns a pointer to a structure that can pretend to represent a number that large:

```
// A Number represents a generic integer with a bounding function limiter. Limit is called after each operations
// to give "fake" bounded integers. New types of Number can be created through NewInitialiser returning a lambda
// with the new Initialiser.
type Number struct {
    num   *big.Int
    limit func(n *Number) *Number
}
```

You might want to consider why you're using a 256-bit type in first place, as the above seems a bit of a kludge.

Comment: As of October 2018, there is no `number` package nor a `Uint256` function in geth. How would you do that now?

Comment: @PaulRBerg do `go get` the repository, then checkout the old commit. or better to vendor it.

Comment: @xpare I see that may work but why doesn't the current [implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/6c313fff7bd7c1935d3193986df4c084b2e34c1c/common/math/big.go#L176) with `U256` work? The number of bytes of `math.U256(big.NewInt(5))` seems to be 1.

Comment: I was just trying to answer your question "How would you do that now?". I haven't even `go get` the package.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure since when exactly, but, as of October 2018, Richard's answer is outdated. You can generate a `uint256` by importing the `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi` package and then doing:

```
var number []byte
number = abi.U256(big.NewInt(3))
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Printf("value: %d\n", number)
fmt.Printf("number of bytes: %d", len(number))
```

Output is:

> value: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3]
>
> number of bytes: 32