# How to represent uint256 in EVM using Golang?

Tags: evm, golang, uint256

I am asked to build a small EVM with few instructions using Golang. What I am confused about is how to represent the uint256 data type? Because Golang supports at most uint64 for integer type. What I thought at first was to store the hex value as string, but I am not sure about how to do math operations on that string, and even if its an acceptable solution. How can I represent the uint256 with Golang?

Or even going further, how will I represent the memory in that case? Because it can grow much much bigger than 32 bytes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this on how to represent uint256 data type using Golang:

[How generate number type uint256 in Go](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20859/how-generate-number-type-uint256-in-go)

Comment: I found that as well but it is outdated :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the currently used package is the following uint256 package:
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/holiman/uint256#section-readme